# Creating a method that queries a database using linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-entities

I currently have multiple methods that do pretty much the same thing but just query different tables.

I am trying to use only one method and pass the method parameters instead so i can skip creating multiple methods and neaten my code.

This is what i have currently:

```
MyEntityModel entity = new MyEntityModel();

private void loadData()
{
    var query = from data in entity.Table1
               select data;

    myDataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
}
```

I want something like this:

```
MyEntityModel entity = new MyEntityModel();

private void loadData(DataGrid dataGrid, Table myTable )
{
    var query = from data in entity.myTable
               select data;

    dataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
}
```

I'm unsure what Type parameter i should pass for myTable
I tried passing it as a `System.Data.Entity.DbSet` and as a `MyEntityModel`

Is something like this even possible using LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create generic method which returns all data from DbSet instance of provided entity type:

```
MyEntityModel entity = new MyEntityModel();

private void LoadData<T>(DataGrid dataGrid)
    where T : class
{    
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = entity.Set<T>().ToList();
}
```

Use it like

```
LoadData<Table1>(myDataGrid); // Table1 is a entity type name
```

Answer (score 0):

While [lazy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18448395/1159478) is one option, the other is to accept an `IQueryable` as a parameter:

```
private void LoadData<T>(DataGrid dataGrid, IQueryable<T> query)
{
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
}
```

You would then call it like:

```
LoadData(dataGrid, entity.Table1);
```